# npm install --global windows-build-tools problem

Tags: npm

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated windows-build-tools@4.0.0: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
Downloading python-2.7.14.amd64.msi
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% of 20.2 MB (3.51 MB/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded python-2.7.14.amd64.msi. Saved to C:\Users\ABC\.windows-build-tools\python-2.7.14.amd64.msi.
Downloading BuildTools_Full.exe
npm ERR! [============================================>] 100.0% of 3.29 MB (3.29 MB/s)
npm ERR! Downloaded BuildTools_Full.exe. Saved to C:\Users\ABC\.windows-build-tools\BuildTools_Full.exe.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Starting installation...
npm ERR! Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor
npm ERR!     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
npm ERR!     at Object.removePath (C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\utils\remove-path.js:11:12)
npm ERR!     at Object.install (C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\install\index.js:29:19)
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\start.js:17:19
npm ERR!     at Object.download (C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\download.js:35:5)
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async Object.aquireInstallers (C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\dist\aquire-installers.js:32:13) {
npm ERR!   code: 'ERR_INVALID_OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! windows-build-tools will now exit.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-18T06_00_13_950Z-debug-0.log
```

how to solve it please

Comment: That package is deprecated, Node now includes the build tools by default. Are you trying to use a very old version of Node?